# Check how many days a country has been independent

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have been using a website called 'CSNewbies' to learn Python and one of the tasks was to create a way for a user to check how many days a country has been independent. The countries are limited to Fiji, Samoa and Australia.

I actually was really proud of the code I wrote because it ended up working. I tried making it a little better at the end by making a fail safe in case the user inputs a different country. However, I wanted to know if my code was too much. Did i write too much at any point?

I feel like for only 3 countries it was quite a big bit of code. Can this be improved?

UPDATE - I asked this in a different forum and was redirected here but I got an answer before the forum was closed. I will type the better code below as I have a few lines I do not understand if anybody could help.

The code that i wrote:

```
# import necessary whatver
from time import strftime
from datetime import date

# set independence days of each country
fiji = date(1970,10,10)
samoa = date(1962,12,13)
australia = date(1901,1,1)

# get todays date
todays_date = date.today()

# get a difference from today and independence days
difffiji = todays_date - fiji
diffsamoa = todays_date - samaoa
diffaustralia = todays_date - australia

# independence checker
print('--Independence Checker--')

#create funct so i can call it at then end as a fail-safe and then it restarts the programme
def indcheck():
    count = input('Choose between Fiji, Samoa,Australia:').lower()
    if count == 'fiji':
        print(f'Fiji has been independent for {difffiji.days} days.')
    elif count == 'samoa':
        print(f'Samoa has been independent for {diffsamoa.days} days.')
    elif count == 'australia':
        print(f'Australia has been independent for {diffaustralia.days} days.')
    else:
        print('Please pick either Fiji, Samoa or Australia!')
        indcheck()


indcheck()
```

Comment: Do you think that `count` is a good name for a variable containing a country name?

Comment: To be honest i misspelt country at first and then i just went with it for some reason but i agree that was stupid

Comment: A very, very useful rule of thumb for *when* you should comment and *what type* of things you should write in comments: "code describes *how* the program works, comments describe *why* the author wrote that code". Comments should describe the *human intent* that led you to writing that specific code. The names you use in your function should be *just* descriptive enough to make it clear to a new reader what the purpose of each variable & function is.

Comment: The second very, very useful rule of thumb I'd recommend to you is this: train yourself to look for *repetitive code*, and then *turn every repetition into an abstraction*. The moment you, as a human writing code for a computer, have to repeat yourself, you should immediately think "is this repetition something that a computer can do, instead of the code author?"

In this case, your repetition could be automated by using a "table"/"hash map" to hold the the names of countries and their independence days, and then using a "loop" or "iteration" to step through each entry and perform tasks.

Answer (score 5):

Delete all of your comments. None of them make the code more obvious than just reading it.

`strftime` is unused so don't import it.

Consider using a dictionary of country names to independence dates instead of separate variables.

Don't do three separate subtractions - just do one.

Your "fail-safe" is a good idea, but you should not recurse; loop instead.

Do not hard-code the country names in your prompt. Just use the keys of your dict instead.

Add a `__main__` guard.

### Suggested

```py
from datetime import date

INDEPENDENCE = {
    'Fiji': date(1970, 10, 10),
    'Samoa': date(1962, 12, 13),
    'Australia': date(1901, 1, 1),
}


def ind_check() -> None:
    print('--Independence Checker--')
    prompt = (
        'Choose between '
        + ', '.join(INDEPENDENCE.keys())
        + ': '
    )

    while True:
        country = input(prompt).title()
        independence = INDEPENDENCE.get(country)
        if independence:
            break

    age = date.today() - independence
    print(f'{country} has been independent for {age.days} days.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ind_check()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The majority made sense. I am new to coding and not just python so this may be an obvious question. But what does the “-> None:” do?

Comment: When you where typing out the prompt you used “independence.keys” what does the “keys” mean

Comment: The rest i will try and research myself what a prompt and a main guard is but thank you for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: _But what does the “-> None:” do?_ - it's a PEP484 type hint indicating that there is no return from the function.

Comment: _what does the “keys” mean_ - this is the collection of keys to the dictionary, i.e. the country names.

Comment: The `prompt` could be a global variable, since it only depends one one other global variable, that is not mutated within the program.